# Let Observables emit first "status" than wait for previous ones to complete

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, reactivex

i want to achieve the following:
I have multiple steps in an initialization, where each step is an observable.
Each step should update his status via a **next()** call, which content is displayed in an Angular template.

They should be executed in sequential order since each steps relies on the step before.

The problem is that all steps should have an initial status, so that the user can at least see all steps even if they observables are not subscribed to yet.

Is there a way to achieve this ? Or do i need to seperate the observable from the displayed data and change that data on each **next()** call ?

Edit: 
Since it seems hard to understand what i want to achieve i try to explain it as an example:
My initialization has 3 steps. *Task 1*, *Task 2*, *Task 3*. For each task a row in the html is displayed with the description of the task and the status (for example *in progress* or *complete*). The description of each task should of course be visible from the very beginning even if some tasks are not yet subscribed to. As soon as the previous task is finished, the next task should start. The update to the task should be delivered via the **next()** call in each Observable.

Edit2: Here is some code with a basic solution:

```
// This is how a basic task should look like
interface Task {
     description: string,
     progressMessage: string,
     status: 'running' | 'idle' | 'complete',
     children: Task[],
     task: Observable<TaskStatus>
}
// This should be the format of each next call
interface TaskStatus {
    progressMessage?: string,
    status?: 'running' | 'idle' | 'complete'
}
// Wait for each task, on complete run next one, is there a better way ?
private async runTasks(): Promise<void> {
    for (let task of this.tasks) {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            task.task.subscribe({
                next: (taskStatus: TaskStatus) => {
                    if (taskStatus.status) {
                        task.status = taskStatus.status;
                    }
                    if (taskStatus.progressMessage) {
                        task.progressMessage = taskStatus.progressMessage;
                    }
                },
                error: (error: Error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    reject(error);
                },
                complete: () => resolve()
            });
        });
    }
}
private registerNewTask(description: string, taskFactory: () => Observable<TaskStatus>): void {
    const taskObservable: Observable<TaskStatus> = taskFactory();
    const newTask: Task = {
        description: description,
        progressMessage: '',
        status: 'idle',
        children: [],
        task: taskObservable
    };
    this.tasks.push(newTask);
}
private task1(): Observable<TaskStatus> {
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer<TaskStatus>) => {
        observer.next({ progressMessage: 'Started', status: 'running' });
        setTimeout(() => {
            observer.next({ progressMessage: 'Finished', status: 'complete' });
            observer.complete();
        }, 10000);
    });
}

private task2(): Observable<TaskStatus> {
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer<TaskStatus>) => {
        observer.next({ progressMessage: 'Started', status: 'running' });
        setTimeout(() => {
            observer.next({ progressMessage: 'Finished', status: 'complete' });
            observer.complete()
        }, 10000);
    });
}
```

This is the only way i found until now. Is there a better way to handle the execution of the tasks ? *concat* seems not work since i need to have access to the whole *Task* object in the *next()* call of the subscription, so i need to manually iterate each one and wait with a promise.

Comment: Is it not better that you let the application change the status and you just do valueChanges?

Comment: Please show some source code that explains the different steps and the initial status.

Comment: That's really hard to understand what is the issue here. You can use for example `BehaviorSubject` for each step... but it really depends on how you want to implement this.